# What are the SSL config that needed for spring Kafka to connect to Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We have enable only ssl encryption in Kafka.
Client authentication is turned off.

We have a spring boot app connecting to it.
Now,

We have set

spring.kafka.security.protocol = "SSL"

Still we are getting 
Kafka listener endpoint registry Timeout exception

What are the config that needed for spring Kafka to connect to Kafka?

Comment: You need keystore and truststore... These should all be documented in Spring Kafka pages

Comment: No don't need keystore when client authentication is disabled

Comment: SSL is not authentication, it is encryption. Yes, you need a security key... Try reading over https://docs.confluent.io/current/security/security_tutorial.html And just go through it without Spring first, then make it work, then copy the relevant configurations over

Comment: I am talking about client authentication on Kafka in which broker verifies client.its already working with Spring .just needed https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html.

Comment: Also ,check this for Ssl authentication https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-ssl-client-authentication-in-multi-tenancy-a. Didnt need server key and worked just fine as we don't have client authentication on Kafka ON,its just ssl encryption. Added security.protocol =Ssl and .worked

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to tell me... `ssl.keystore.location` + `ssl.keystore.password` + `ssl.truststore.location` + `ssl.truststore.password` are clearly mentioned in that post. Again, **authentication (SASL_PLAINTEXT + SCRAM) is not encryption (SSL/TLS)**

Comment: From the link-"You can configure SSL for encryption or authentication. You can configure just SSL encryption (by default, SSL encryption includes certificate authentication of the server)".  Again,We did not have client authentication 
enabled only tls encryption.didnt need truststore configurations. Just we added security.protocol = SSL. AND it is solved.Do not see the point in having further discussion on this. It's solved.

Comment: How is it solved? You said you got timeout issues after adding that... If it is solved, then put your answer below rather than as a comment

Comment: Hi,answer put and it was the right config . We restarted the services and spring seemed to work perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved by putting the config spring.kafka.security.protocol = "SSL" for the consumers